# Como mostrar un componente modal desde cualquier parte de la web

Tags: vue.js

Hola Tengo un componente para modal el cual voy a utilizar en toda mi aplicacion desde distintos modulos

```
<template>
<div>    
<b-modal v-model="modalShow">Hello From Modal!</b-modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   data() {
      return {
        modalShow: false
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Ese componente lo importe de manera global y quisiera que cuando de click en otro boton de otro componente me abre ese modal, he intentado con

```
@click.prevent="$emit('ComponentModal')"
```

No he obtenido resultados

Comment: Supongo que tendrías que pasarle ese `modalShow` como `prop` a tu componente `modal` para que el componente padre le indique si se muestra o no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en tus props una variable visible

```
props: {
      visible: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
      },
```

entonces donde lo quieras usar le debes mandar una variable bool

```
<ConfirmationDialog
        :visible="tuVariableBoolean"
      />
```